# Clojure - StuartSierraComponent Start

Tags: clojure

I am having a little trouble starting my app.

Here is my core.clj

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:require [yada.yada :as yada :refer [resource as-resource]]
            [yada.resources.file-resource :refer [new-directory-resource]]
            [aero.core :refer [read-config]]
            [web.view :as view]
            [web.routes :as routes]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [aero.core :refer [read-config]]
            [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer (refresh)]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]))

(defrecord Listener [listener]
  component/Lifecycle
  (start [component]
    (assoc component :listener (yada/listener
                                 ["/"
                                  [(view/view-route)
                                   routes/route-handler
                                   ["public/" (new-directory-resource (io/file "target/cljsbuild/public") {})]
                                   [true (as-resource nil)]]]           )))
  (stop [component]
    (when-let [close (-> component :listener :close)]
      (close))
    (assoc component :listener nil)))

(defn new-system []
  (component/system-map
    :listener (map->Listener {})
    ))

(def system nil)

(defn init []
  (alter-var-root #'system
                  (constantly (new-system))))

(defn start []
  (alter-var-root #'system component/start))

(defn stop []
  (alter-var-root #'system
                  (fn [s] (when s (component/stop s)))))

(defn go []
  (init)
  (start))

(defn reset []
  (stop)
  (refresh :after 'web.core/go))

(defn -main
  [& [port]]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port (env :port) 3300))]
    (jetty/run-jetty (component/start (new-system)) {:port port :join? false})))
```

I am testing out Stuart Sierra's library, component.

I can start the app if I do `lein repl` and `(go)` but I am trying to start my app by running `lein run` (to see what the app is like if I deployed it in production). When I do `lein run` in the browser I get the error

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /view. Reason:

    com.stuartsierra.component.SystemMap cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I am confused because I don't know why the system-map (in `new-system`) is the error. I'm also not sure what the error means so I don't know how to fix it

Could someone please help. Thanks

Comment: can you reproduce this problem by starting a fresh repl, (or jacking-in from emacs), changing to the myapp.core namespace, and evaluating `(-main "8080")`

Answer (score 1):

Your `-main` function calls [`jetty/run-jetty`](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.adapter.jetty.html) function first argument of which must be a Ring handler - function which accepts request map and produces response map. You're passing a system instead which leads to the exception. Exception means that jetty adapter tries to call passed system as a function, but can't, because system is actually a record and doesn't implement function interface `IFn`.

I'm not that familiar with `yada`, but it looks like `yada/listener` starts the (Aleph) server, so there's no need to explicitly call the jetty adapter. Your `main` should look something like this:

`(defn -main [& [port]]
  (component/start (new-system)))`

Port (or any other config) could be passed as an argument to the `new-system` and then forwarded to components requiring it (in your case port should be passed down to the `Listener` and then to `yada/listener` call in `start` implementation).